# how to link href to a div id tag jquery slider parallax slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm working on the jquery slider (sequence master parallax). I would like to add a menu at the top which allows users to jump to each slide. My problem is that I don't manage to link my href to my div id. Actually, I don't know how to proceed. For example, when you click on Menu 1 it goes to the slide which has the div id="menu1". My other problem if I add between `<li class="animate-in"> <div id="menu1"> ... </div></li>` it breaks all the animation.
Here the code :
    
    
        
        
        Sequence Theme Demo - Sliding Horizontal Parallax
        
        
        
        
         if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
            document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="../../scripts/jquery-min.js" %3E%3C/script%3E'));
         }

```
</head>
<body>  
<menu-->
    <nav>
    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--end menu-->
    <div id="sequence">


        <img class="sequence-prev" src="images/bt-prev.png" alt="Previous" />
        <img class="sequence-next" src="images/bt-next.png" alt="Next" />

        <ul class="sequence-canvas">

            <li class="animate-in">


                <div class="info">
                    <h2>Built using Sequence.js</h2>
                    <p>The Responsive Slider with Advanced CSS3 Transitions</p>
                </div>
                <img class="sky" src="images/bg-clouds.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                <img class="balloon" src="images/balloon.png" alt="Balloon" />

            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>Creative Control</h2>
                    <p>Create unique sliders using CSS3 transitions -- no jQuery knowledge required!</p>
                </div>
                <img class="sky" src="images/bg-clouds.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                <img class="aeroplane" src="images/aeroplane.png" alt="Aeroplane" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>Cutting Edge</h2>
                    <p>Supports modern browsers, old browsers (IE7+), touch devices and responsive designs</p>
                </div>
                <img class="sky" src="images/bg-clouds.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                <img class="kite" src="images/kite.png" alt="Kite" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a href link like this

```
<a href="your link">
<li class="animate-in">
                <div class="info">
                    <h2>Built using Sequence.js</h2>
                    <p>The Responsive Slider with Advanced CSS3 Transitions</p>
                </div>
                <img class="sky" src="images/bg-clouds.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                <img class="balloon" src="images/balloon.png" alt="Balloon" />

            </li>
</a>
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply. The problem, if I had the href tag where u said, it destroys the animation. Plus, I would like to go to different slides by using the menu which in nav tag. Regards, Eric.

Comment: Then you can make href link to another child tag such as <div class="info">
                    <h2>Built using Sequence.js</h2>
                    <p>The Responsive Slider with Advanced CSS3 Transitions</p>
                </div>